# Reporting Service Pagination Problem with IE

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Reporting Services SSRS Version 15.0.1102.675 on Windows Server 2019 Standard and accessing it from Windows 10 Pro using IE browser, when opening the page I get strange names on the page controls for example: instead of right arrow > I get the letter D (for Next) and I get the letter C instead of having the left arrow <.

I tried to reset the settings of the browser to the default but it didn't help. Browsing in Chrome seems to work just fine and as expected. Please see the attached picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKkoZ.png)

Comment: IE is not great with SSRS after about 2014/16, it may not even be supported but you would have to look into that. You will find that Chrome, Firefox, Brave, Edge and a few others will work just fine. You could try compatibility mode but I'm not sure that will help

Comment: Thank you, I did download Edge and its working great. Its just odd how IE displays it.

Comment: IE was built before MS decided to build their browser almost like everyone else did rather than their own interpretation. It was also before SSRS used HTML5. The latest version of Edge uses the Chromium rendering engine, same engine that Chrome, Brave and a couple of others use, so they are all similar enough to be fine to use.